# Jenkins start the build if it satisfies the condition

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to start the Jenkins build by checking the condition.

EX :- Let a file with name `HDB1.txt` in the workspace, and the build has to check for this file, if file is there then Build has to fail and need to send the mail as listed in the Email notification.

I've tried with "Run Conditions Extra Plugin",
this is not working completely, and I've configured as shown in pic.

[image: Conditional steps (multiple) - configuration]

If the file is there then I need to fail the build, so I set evaluation failure as "Fail the Build". But this is not failing the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by adding a pre-build step in which you will make your checks with a script shell for exemple.

Hope that help you.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud Broc for your quick answer, i'm using Jenkins ver. 1.642.1.

Here i'm not able to see this Pre-Build step option. So can you please explain how to do this.

Comment: "In the build section of a Jenkins project there is an option to "Add build step". There is no icon indicating you can do so, but you actually can then simply DRAG that build step above your actual build section. This will be a pre-build step."